# mulitpy certain field results from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, multiplication

hello im new to mysql so forgive me lol but i have a bunch of items in a database. 
On the webpage im accessing these items from will show the result of the item then on the other side it will show the result of the same item but the data in 5/11 fields would be multiplied by 2.

I have tried a bunch of suggestions on these forums just trying to figure it out but i think im just lost.

so my table is called items.

it has 22 columns such as name attack hp ept rpt mr and a bunch more.

so i am able to call up the item directly for this example with

```
    <?php
        error_reporting(1);
        $con =  mysql_connect("localhost","loginname","pass"); 
        if (!$con) {
            die("Can Not Connect: " . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("db_name",$con);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM  `items` WHERE (`items`.`item_id` =223)";
        $myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);
        while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){

        echo '<img src="/images/items/wozring_zpsyjxzc5cd.gif" alt=ring>';  
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<strong>Item Name: </strong>";
        echo $record['name'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<strong>Item Slot: </strong>";
        echo $record['slot'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<strong>Attack: </strong>";       
        echo $record['attack'];
        echo "<br>";
```

i've seen in other post and other topics on multiplying that i should be using something like

```
$sql = "SELECT attack, hp, ept, rpt, mr ) FROM  `items`  WHERE (`items`.`item_id` =223) * 2";
```

but like i said i am like 4-5 hours into learning this so forgive me if im totally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Put the multiplication in the `SELECT` list.

```
SELECT *, attack * 2 AS attack_double, 
        hp * 2 as hp_double,
        ept * 2 as ept_double,
        rpt * 2 as rpt_double,
        mr * 2 as mr_double
FROM items
WHERE item_id = 223
```

You could also just do the multiplication in PHP: `echo $record['attack'] * 2;`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of multiplying the whole query, you should multiply the fields.

Something like this my young padawan:

```sql
SELECT
  attack as 'baseAttackDamage',
  attack * 2 as 'buffedAttackDamage',
  hp as 'baseHP',
  hp * 2 as 'buffedHP'
FROM items
WHERE item_id = 223
```

Now you can display the base attack damage with: `$row['baseAttackDamage']` or the buffed power: `$row['buffedAttackDamage']`. Using aliases for fields.

And when the items contain the buff power property/column (items.buffPower) you can do it dynamically instead of the default 2x buff power:

```sql
SELECT
  attack as 'baseAttackDamage',
  attack * buffPower as 'buffedAttackDamage',
  hp as 'baseHP',
  hp * buffPower as 'buffedHP'
FROM items
WHERE item_id = 223
```